# Stepping through the debbuger in qtcreator causes gdb crash after a couple seconds

Tags: c++, gdb, qt-creator

After I step through any code in this file in particular in a static library, gdb crashes after a couple of seconds.

I can step through other parts of the static library and shared libs that I have loaded and it works fine. The program runs fine and does not crash after gdb crashes.

gdb version 7.5.91.20130417-cvs-ubuntu on linux mint 15

How do I stop gdb from crashing in qtcreator?

Comment: Now can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GDB is crashing, that sounds like a bug in GDB, from their [docs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Bug-Criteria.html):

> If the debugger gets a fatal signal, for any input whatever, that is a gdb bug.
>   Reliable debuggers never crash.

Which version are you running/does upgrading to a newer version help?

Comment: gdb version 7.5.91.20130417-cvs-ubuntu on linux mint 15

Comment: Upstream GDB is 7.6. So, if you have time you could try compiling their sources. Otherwise I'd suggest to build a test case to reproduce this and report this to the Linux Mint bugtracker.

Comment: Updating to 7.6 made it stop crashing.

Answer (score 0):

provided as a supplementation:

I also encounter this gdb crash with qtcreator 5.0,after upgrade to qtcreator 6.0.1 ,error still existed with
"gdb crashed unexpectedly exit"

run the qt project is ok,when debugging ,and the qtcreator hit a breakpoint ,gdb will crash in about 3 seconds.

how I fix it:

remove cached QtProject folder under current user.

`find . -name QtProject`

in current user directory.
and remove the folder.